# Run button disabled in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, import

I downloaded a project from GitHub, extracted it then opened it as existing project in Android Studio but run button is disabled and the project can not be displayed as "Android" ... Any help ?

Answer (score 5):

Try File -> Sync project with gradle Files

or if that doesn't help

Rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of opening it as an existing project, import it using File -> New -> Import